# C++ Write string to beginning of file

Tags: c++, string

I have a file that is like

> This is line 1
>
> This is line 2

and I have a string `This is line 0`. How do I write this string into the beginning of the file so the contents of the file is now:

> This is line 0
>
> This is line 1
>
> This is line 2

I currently have

```
ifstream myfile("lunch.txt");
myfile.seekg(0,ios::beg);
myfile << "This is line 0";
```

But it is not working as expected.

Comment: Because you need to move the rest to fit the new line in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work to write to an `std::ifstream` (that is meant for input). Change your code to use a `std::ofstream` for writing output:

```
   ofstream myfile("lunch.txt");
// ^^^^^^^^
   // myfile.seekg(0,ios::beg); <<< this code isn't necessary
   myfile << "This is line 0";
```

To solve your problems about inserting before the existing content, you 1st read in the file, while  saving the content in e.g. a `std::vector<std::string> lines;`. Then you open your file again, write the 1st line, and followed up with the values saved in `lines`.

Comment: But this code overwrites the beginning of the file. The question was how to _insert_ content in the beginning of the file.

Comment: @Weston Didn't I cover this?

Comment: Oh, yes -- sorry bout that..! :) Didn't see that part first time. Did you add it later? Anyway, you are correct. Only comment I have, is that if the size of the original file could be very large, then reading it into a vector might be a problem.

Comment: @Weston Straight copying after, would be more efficient of course, but that would need a rename/remove operation for either the old backup, or a newly created file.

Comment: I am getting an error. `'std::ofstream' has no member named 'seekg'  myfile.seekg(0,ios::beg);`

Comment: @Bijan You can omit this statement at all, it makes no sense here.

Answer (score 1):

You can't insert into the beginning of a file and have the existing content move automatically.

Your best bet is to open a new file and write "This is line 0", and then copy over the content of the existing file.